# Is there any equivalent of Norse Mythology event: RAGNAROK in Hindu Mythology?

Tags: belief, dharma, other-religions

I was curious if there exists any `RAGNAROK` like an event in Hindu Mythology as it does in Norse Mythology. If it does exist, then how are they similar and if it does not exist, then why?

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! A question-Answer site about Hinduism. Yours is a intresting question. But there is already a similar type question present on this site and the answer of your questions is provided in that Pls. see - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28659/5620 Pls. continue your participation on the site by asking and answering posts and also do check existing question and answers.

Comment: Well no since in Ragnarok a part of society still lives. Also, in Ragnarok 1 one of the many (interconnected) worlds ends partly.